# Do I have to format win 7 if same motherboard bought new

Tags: windows-7, motherboard, formatting

I have this motherboard GA-78LMT-S2 (Socket M2) it's slow now. So was planning to buy the same new one. But I am worried that I may have to format my PC when changing the motherboard.

I heard that if the chipset is same then I don't need to format.

Comment: Could you explain why you want to replace your Motherboard? A slow PC *usually* has nothing to do with the Motherboard.

Comment: I'd always plan on backing up, and then reformatting and reinstalling on a motherboard change, unless it was exactly the same motherboard.

Comment: I meant to say that the PC is slow now

Answer (score 0):

No, because you are using the same Motherboard Model you don't have to format or reinstall Windows 7 when replacing it. You may have to change some BIOS/UEFI settings.